# Can I use Facebook instant article on custom website?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I developed a custom website which is totally dynamic. It is an online newspaper. I searched on google and youtube to know how to connect with facebook instant article. I only found plugin for wordpress. I could not get any tutorial or help to connet with custom website. what to do to set instant article to my custom website?

Comment: An instant article is supposed to be a light-weight version of an article that a “full” version of exists on an external website in the first place ... so I’m not seeing what sense this would be supposed to make.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create fb instant article for your custom website. You can do it by API or RSS FEED. You can create rss feed for your website. Then connect the website rss feed with your fb fan page. if your rss feed is okay then it will automatically sync your website post to facebook instant article. you might want to know about formatting of rss feed. [check this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/publishing/setup-rss-feed#rss-import) ..you will get all the information here!